# Autostart in windows from other os

Tags: windows, autostart

How to add a program to autostart in Windows without turning the OS on?
I've considered using USB Bootable Linux, but where should I put my program? If I put shortcut into `Autostart` folder will it work?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? You want to go to a computer, add a program to the OS, and then put that program in the autostart folder so that the next time Windows is booted it will start?

Comment: @Abraxas That's the case.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot install a new program to windows while it is offline. You can do things in the filesystem (ie, move a shortcut to the startup items folder) but you can't 'install' a program and then move the shortcut while it is offline.

Comment: Well, it doesn't require installing. It's just an exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description in the comments you can do this with any distro you can boot from other media (USB drive, etc). After getting access to the windows FS you can add the file to the startup items folder:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

I have not tested this using an .exe but I imagine it will work okay. If not, create a shortcut to that file and put the shortcut there.

Adding this just in case you don't know how to get to the Windows partition from a live distro of linux, etc. - https://askubuntu.com/questions/186791/how-to-access-files-in-windows-partition-from-ubuntu-live-usb

Basically, you just need to mount the partition as a folder and go in through that folder :)

Hope this helps!